# duplicate symbol linker error when including -Swift.h in Objective-c .m file

Tags: objective-c, swift

I get a duplicate symbol linker errors in my project during a build when I import the target `-Swift.h` file.  If I don't include this header file and comment out use of swift classes the project builds.  In my Obj-C `.m` file I have this:

`#import "MyTarget-Swift.h"`

Without this import the compiler doesn't recognize the swift classes I am using in the source file, and I get a compiler error.

The linker errors refer in my Obj-C source file and another Obj-C file to 3rd party library symbols, not my Swift class files.  The 3rd party library header is declared in my bridging header file:

`#import <My3rdPartyLibrary/My3rdPartyLibraryHeader.h>`

I'm on Xcode 9.4.1 and using Swift 4.1.

EDIT: I have kept the `#import "MyTarget-Swift.h"` and removed 1 out of the 5 Swift files from the target, and the project builds.  Only the removed file out of the 5 had references to the 3rd party library.  This leads me to believe that the compiler is not reconciling correctly the referenced symbols or somehow is including the references libraries twice.

Comment: Do you have classes with same name in swift and objec ??

Comment: No.  They are unique file names and class names.

Comment: @Sh_Khan The duplicate symbol errors refer to a 3rd party library.  That 3rd party library header is included in my bridging header.  Maybe there's a connection there, but I still don't understand why I would get these errors.

Comment: you can change swift classes names say with a new prefix and try again

Comment: @Sh_Khan The swift class names have nothing to do with the duplicate symbols.  The duplicate symbols are references to the 3rd party library symbols.  The duplicate references are from two Obj-C files.

Comment: you said it gives error only when you import swift bridge , btw change objc class names if there is a duplicate with 3rd

Comment: Make sure you only import _.h_ files, and ideally only into _.m_ files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate+symbol+linker+objective-c+swift

Comment: The issue was resolved, but the solution involved modifying the 3rd party library header file.  I believe the steps I used are correct and the issue is unknown.